# Meteor how to get all users

Tags: javascript, meteor

How can I get all the users on the system, but for security reasons only get certain fields from it. I do not want to return the entire objects as it would have fields in there that are private.

I have a publish method:
I am unsure if I need an import?
The fields I need are:
- username
- age
- level

```
Meteor.publish("allUsers", function(){
return Meteor.users.find({});
});
```

on the client side I have:

```
    allUsers(){
        Meteor.call('allUsers', function(error, result) {
            return result;
        });
    }
```

and in the render I have:

```
        {this.allUsers().map((user) => {
            return <UserSearchRow
            key={user._id} 
            user={user} />
        })}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Meteor.publish("allUsers", function() {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {username: 1, age: 1, level: 1}});
});
```

https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#fieldspecifiers

Comment: Hi  I have edited my question to input more detail: I am having trouble trying to get this list of users fields from the client side..

Comment: `Meteor.call` is meant to be used for methods, not publications. You need to use `Meteor.subscribe` instead.